# How to elegantly read the size of the first list<int> in the list<list<int>>?

Tags: c++, list, std

I have a `list<list<int>>`, and I want to read the `size` of the first `list<int>` on the list, but I will still have to loop through the `list<list<int>>` later.

So currently what I do is that I have to use `front()` to get the size, and then use `back()` to rollback the iterator pointer:

```
        int rowCount = vList.front().size();
        vList.back();
        for (auto iterator = vList.begin(); iterator != vList.end();++iterator)
        {
          //do iterator access here
        }
```

which I think is not elegant at all.

Is there anyway that I can do this in a more elegant way?

Comment: *then use back() to rollback the iterator pointer:* That's not necessary at all.

Comment: You should read some [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list). `list::back` doesn't do what you think it does. You can delete that line and your code will behave the same.

Comment: If you are talking about elegance and already using c++11 standard you could write the for loop like `for (auto &it: vList) { do stuff }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read [the documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) wrongly; `front()` and `back()` just access the first and last element on the list and they don't advance the iterator at all.

So my code will work just fine if I delete the `back()` line.